# How to connect a MacBook to two external monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, macbook, hdmi

I'm trying to connect my two monitors to my old Macbook (2008) with one Mini DisplayPort connection, but I only get my two monitors showing up the same thing on the screen with a splitter. I want to use them separately, but can't.

None of them has a HDMI or RGB out, only in. My macbook has a Mini Displayport out. What do I need to buy so that it will show separately on the screen? Or do I need to sell one of monitors and buy me a new one that has a HDMI out?

My two monitors are both Samsung S22D300HY with VGA and HDMI inputs.

Comment: Are you sure your laptop has a Thunderbolt port because it didn't even exist until 2011.  **The information does not compute.**

Comment: The name of the Mac is Macbook Aluminium, I think it was one of the first macbooks that came in Aluminium, I'm not sure. I googled a little and it looks like it came out in 2008, but I didn't get it before 2009.

Comment: You were right @Ramhound. I confusted the thunderbolt and the Mini DisplayPort!

Comment: The GPU in your system does not support 2 monitors which is the reason the splitter did what it did.  You can try and use a docking station designed for your laptop though.

Comment: Could you clarify what inputs are available on each of your two monitors?

Comment: @Jason This is the one I have http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-S22D300HY-21-5-Inch-LED-lit-Monitor/dp/B00IEZH006
Input: VGA/HDMI

Comment: You have two of the same monitor?

Comment: Yes, I have both of the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have two external displays connected to your MacBook Pro which only supports one external display.

The only way around this is to install a USB video adapter such as [this one](http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-to-HDMI-External-Dual-or-Multi-Monitor-Video-Adapter-with-Audio~USB2HDMI).  These adapters are relatively expensive and have poor performance, but it is your only option.

Comment: Nice, I will look in to that. Could this one work? http://www.thruthewireusa.com/Displayport-to-2-HDMI-Splitter.html or another one?

Comment: @FelipeSepulveda No, that's something entirely different.  You want something with a USB port and a monitor output (i.e. VGA, DVI, DisplayPort).

Comment: Since your monitor doesn't have DVI, I replaced the link with an HDMI version.  You could use VGA as well, but these often don't support resolutions as high as 1920x1080.

Comment: it worked perfectly fine! I bought a 3.0 USB to HDMI adapter from UNITEK and I'm really pleased with the result. Even tho I wouldn't recommend it for gamers that wants to use this solution for another display to game on. It works good when you have the latest driver and fits perfectly for my needs as reading, writing and surfing the web. :D
I bought this one: http://www.unitek-products.com/en/product_detail.php?id=241